# PHP form throwing errors - Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to implement php for a simple form.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Hola'; 
$to = 'test@yahoo.com'; 
$subject = 'Hola';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
} else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
}
?>

<form class="form" method="post" action="say-hello.php">
    
    <label>Name</label>
    <input name="name" placeholder="Spongebob" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Whoa, you can't leave this blank!">
        
    <label>Email</label>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="squarepants@krustykrab.com" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Whoa, you can't leave this blank!" data-errormessage-type-mismatch="Something isn't right...">
        
    <label>Message</label>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Well Hello!" required data-errormessage-value-missing="Whoa, you can't leave this blank!"></textarea>

    <div class="bttnholder">       
    <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" placeholder="Send">
    </div>
    
</form>
```

I can't figure out why part of my PHP is displayed as HTML and why I get the following errors on page:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\say-hello.php on line 35
>
> Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\say-hello.php on line 36
>
> Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\say-hello.php on line 37

Any help to get this code working?

---

The following are lines 35,36,37.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

Comment: Can you identify which lines in "say-hello.php" are 35, 36, and 37?

Comment: I added it as an edit @Helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $_POST['submit'] is obsolete, as you should check for the correct form inputs.
I check for every form input to be set and not to be empty. If one of them is empty or not set -> error.
If all fields are given -> send the mail.

```
<?php

    $from = 'From: Hola'; 
    $to = 'test@yahoo.com'; 
    $subject = 'Hola';

    if(
        !isset($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['message']) || empty($_POST['message'])
    ){
        echo '<p>Please fill in all fields</p>';
    }else{
        $body = "From: " . $_POST['name'] . "\n E-Mail: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n Message:\n " . $_POST['message'] . "";
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: of course you could also check for every input on their own to provide a better error message ;-)

Comment: The line only appears if you haven't submitted all fields.
If you do not want to have an error displayed, just remove the line.

Optional you could also reverse the statement...

Comment: By remove the line you mean omit echo '<p>Please fill in all fields</p>'; @Vestalis

Answer (score 2):

You must first check variable to set. Try this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $from = 'From: Hola'; 
  $to = 'test@yahoo.com'; 
  $subject = 'Hola';
  if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
    echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
  } else { 
    echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
  }
}
```

Comment: It sent part of the message and gave this error:                          Notice: Undefined variable: body in C:\xampp\htdocs\sandbox\say-hello.php on line 42
Your message has been sent!

Comment: Yes. It's my fault. Please change $body to $message. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the Notices, you should change your php to:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
}
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}
if(isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
}
$from = 'From: Hola'; 
$to = 'test@yahoo.com'; 
$subject = 'Hola';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if (isset($_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'])) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        echo '<p>Your message has been sent!</p>';
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mail function is wrong, there is no "from" argument in it, if you want a from argument your mail function should be like this:

First define a headers variable:

```
$headers = "From: $from";
```

And your mail function:

```
mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert these lines inside the if statement.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: Hola'; 
$to = 'test@yahoo.com'; 
$subject = 'Hola';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";
```

When the html page loads, the name for example doesn't exists. It's been set after clicking on the submit button. So if you put it inside the if statement, the script will read the variables only after the submit button is posted.

Anyway, for your future consideration, these are not errors, are warnings, the script still works.